# By default in OpenEBS NDM (Node Disk Manager) runs in privileged one. Can we run it in non-privileged mode in OpenEBS.

Tags: kubernetes, openebs

by default node disk manager container runs as a privileged one and on K8s cluster, we've implemented Pod security Policies(PSP) and this psp disallow containers running in privileged mode.
Is there any other way to get the cStor disks from hosts with any specific privilege?